# Installing web3

Tags: web3js, installation

I was struggling with this problem for couple days, who know how to fix that ? Win7

```
C:\Users\Administrator>npm install web3
    npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Suppor
    t
    npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecat
    ed and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://np
    mjs.com/tar

    > scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\scrypt
    > node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


    > scrypt@6.0.3 install C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\scrypt
    > node-gyp rebuild


    C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (n
    ode "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\np
    m-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
      else (node "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_m
    odules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
    Warning: Missing input files:
    C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\scrypt\build\..\scrypt\win\include\config.h
    Generate one project at a time in this solution. To enable parallel generation, add the "/m" switch.
      Copying scrypt/win/include/config.h to scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/config.h
      The system can not find the file specified.
      win_delay_load_hook.cc
    LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'LTCG:INCREMENTAL' [C:\Users
    \Administrator\node_modules\scrypt\build\copied_files.vcxproj]
      memlimit.c
      keyderivation.c
      pickparams.c
      hash.c
      win_delay_load_hook.cc
      scrypt_wrapper.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\scrypt\build\Re
      lease\\scrypt_wrapper.lib
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail
    ed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roamin
    g\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
    s.js:240:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator
    \\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gy
    p.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\scrypt
    gyp ERR! node -v v10.13.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN prop-types-extra@1.1.0 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none is in
    stalled. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-bootstrap@0.32.4 requires a peer of react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 but
     none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-bootstrap@0.32.4 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0
     but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-overlays@0.8.3 requires a peer of react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 but n
    one is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-overlays@0.8.3 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0 b
    ut none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-prop-types@0.4.0 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 but none is in
    stalled. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-transition-group@2.5.0 requires a peer of react@>=15.0.0 but none
     is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN react-transition-group@2.5.0 requires a peer of react-dom@>=15.0.0 but
    none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN uncontrollable@5.1.0 requires a peer of react@>=15.0.0 but none is inst
    alled. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN administrator@1.0.0 No description
    npm WARN administrator@1.0.0 No repository field.

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
    ging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-09T1
    6_16_09_054Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you install windows build tools?

Comment: yes i did @ivicaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error took me long time of reaserch, but now finnaly i solved that, will share the steps if someone needs:
1)First reinstall your node version to [8.11.3](https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/), i found out that this is currently the most stable version.
2)Then install `windows-build-tools` by typing in cmd

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

While downloading `windows-build-tools` i had another error such as

```
spawn powershell.exe enoent
```

Just find your `WindowsPowerShell` path and add it to `System Variable`

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

re-open the console and try to install `windows-build-tools` again, if it still doesn't work delete your `.node-gyp` file and reinstall node-gyp. After that you can easily install all  WinTools
[3] These steps basically solved my initial question, and now i'm able to install `web3`. Of course besides these dependencies you also need to install other dependencies such as `Git` and `Python(2.7.14-recomended version)`,but i did it yet before